# UIButton position issue on CGAffineTransformScale of parent view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uibutton, cgaffinetransform, cgaffinetransformscale

I have a `UIView` that I scale, pan and rotate with a `UIButton` added to it as subview at `(0,0)` with width and height of `50px`.

This button acts as a trigger for an editing functionality. The problem I'm having is that when I scale the `UIView` using `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` added to the `UIView` such that it shrinks, I invert the transform on the `UIButton` so that its size stays constant.

However due to the `UIView` scale changing, it results in the `UIButton` frame extending outside the parent `UIView`. This renders part of the button unclickable. I would like to have the button stay within the parent `UIView`, fixed at its origin at all times like when it was added, how do I go about doing this?

I've added the `UIPinchGestureRecognizer` handler code below.

Thanks in advance.

```
- (void)scaleView:(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {

    recognizer.view.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(recognizer.view.transform, recognizer.scale, recognizer.scale);

    self.editBtn.transform = CGAffineTransformInvert(recognizer.view.transform);

    recognizer.scale = 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is working just like as it should
You defined the frame.origin for your UIButton (0,0) in its containing view and every time you scale the view it's frame changes.

CGAffineTransformInvert inverses the scale happened on the button but you need to change its origin in the containing view

Every time you scale your view it's frame changes and the button in the same place
UIButton frame.origin is (0,0) and you never changed it

You can change the frame.origin of the UIButton every time you scale the containing view or you can put your UIButton outside the view you're trying to scale

Comment: I did try that but the resultant position still doesn't work as well as it should. Could you share relevant code for the same?

Comment: You don't want to put it in another view?